Quality control and quality control table in SSIS using DQS
I am working on DWH doing incremental load in staging from application database then doing quality checking and loading the data data in reporting schema with rows having flag as 0/1(for errors) using SSIS and wanted to create data quality table which stores the table name, ID, error and time about the row having error.
Is it possible to do using DQS in SSIS. Like logging the quality table.
If is it possible then, how?

Yes, This is how it's done:
Configure DQS Knowledge Base: Define data quality rules and create a knowledge base in DQS that specifies the criteria for valid data.
Integrate DQS into SSIS Package: Use the DQS Cleansing component within your SSIS package to apply data quality rules to your data flow. This component allows you to perform cleansing operations and identify errors based on the defined rules.
Error Output Handling: Configure the SSIS data flow components to handle error outputs. When errors occur during the data quality checks, direct these error rows to an error output path within the SSIS package.
Logging Errors to Data Quality Table: After directing error rows to an error output path, use SSIS components such as "Derived Column" or "Conditional Split" to extract relevant information (e.g., table name, row ID, error description, timestamp) from the error rows.
Insert Records into Data Quality Table: Finally, use SSIS components like "OLE DB Destination" to insert the extracted error information into the data quality table in your reporting schema.
Or follow bellow tutorials:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dsK5e3emhyg
https://medium.com/@smitagudale712/data-quality-services-dqs-cleansing-transformation-in-ssis-a32c3d423d46
